# Collect a distinct list of key values from a nested collection?

Tags: c#, linq

This seems like it is completely straightforward, but my brain isn't working very well this morning, and I can't seem to find a good search expression for the answer.

I have an `IList<IDictionary<string, string>>` and I want to get an `IList<string>` containing a distinct list of unique key names in my collection of dictionary objects.  What's a quick and elegant way to do this?  I'm sure the answer is simple, I just can't think of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var allKeys = from dict in list
              from key in dict.Keys
              select key;

var distinctKeys = allKeys.Distinct().ToList();
```

Or if you prefer lambda syntax:

```
var distinctKeys = list.SelectMany(dict => dict.Keys).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Hah I knew it was gonna be a "duh" moment for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
list.SelectMany(d => d.Keys).Distinct()
```